# How to show suggestion of my custom component properties installed from npm in vscode?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I just tried to create my own custom component for React Native, i just tried it directly inside vscode editor and it's works.

[image: Works]

but when i install it from npm, my properties not showing up

[image]

how to make it works like 1st pick above?

here's my source code on [github](https://github.com/zxccvvv/react-native-flixcomponent)

Comment: You have to use typescript for that.

Comment: So why vscode can show my props (1st pic)